# Changing data-processing-sources attribute of canvas? (Processing.js)

Tags: javascript, java, html, processing, processing.js

I'm really ignorant, just learning right now. so i've already tried a lot and have this... (which doesn't work) PLEASE HELP.
please note that i'm using .js instead of .pde, i don't know why is the only way it worked on the canvas.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
           <title>Hello Web - Processing.js Test</title>
        <script src="Scripts/processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/processing.js"></script>


       </head>
    <body>   
         <canvas data-processing-sources="H.js" id="canvas" ></canvas>
            <footer>
      <input id="giro" onclick="giro()" type="button"  name="giro" value="giro"/>

    <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
        function giro() {

            document.getElementById('canvas').setAttribute("data-processin‌​g-sources", "giro.js");
//i've also tried:            
document.getElementById('canvas').data-Processing-sources="giro.js";

          }

     </SCRIPT>

            </footer>   
    </body>
    </html>
```

H.js code:

```
String[] mp;
PFont Gobold;
float x, y;
float hr, vr;
String pala = "mp.length()";



void setup () {
    size(innerWidth-15,innerHeight-45);
 noCursor();
 background (255);
 textAlign(CENTER, CENTER);
  hr = textWidth(pala) / 2;
  vr = (textAscent() + textDescent()) / 3000;
  noStroke();
 // x = width / 2;
 // y = height / 2;
  Gobold = loadFont("Verdana-8.vlw");;
  textFont (Gobold);
  mp = loadStrings ("H.txt");
    }

void draw () {
 fill(255);
  rect(0, 0, width, height);
  fill(0,255,0);
  for (int i = 0; i<mp.length; i++)
  {
    text (mp [i++], random(0,width), (mouseY));
  }
}
```

and giro.js code:

```
Ball b;
void setup()
{
    size(1000, 1000);
   background(100);
}

void draw()
{

  background(100);
  if (b==null){
    b=new Ball(50,50);
}
b.update();
b.draw();
}

class Ball {
   int x,y;
   int yV;
   int gravity;

   Ball(int initX,int initY) {
       x = initX;
       y = initY;
       yV = 1;
       gravity = 1;
   }

   void update(){
     yV += gravity;
     y +=yV;
     if (y>480){
       yV=-20;
   }
   }

   void draw() {
     translate(width/2, height/2);
     ellipse(x,y,20,20);
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hi Kevin. i really don't know what's wrong with my code, the button seems to do nothing. IT JUST DOESN'T CHANGE IT :(

Comment: Hey no need to shout at me. But if you want help, you really need to poast a [mcve] that we can run. Can you put together a jsfiddle or CodePen that contains your code? In its current state we have no way of running your code, which makes it impossible for us to debug and help you.

Comment: Why are you trying to switch sketches like this? What goal are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Kevin sorry, it wasn't my intention. this is my first question here, i'm learning now. i'm gonna change the code for easy running, thanks so much. is just a little experiment :)

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I'm not really surprised that it doesn't work the way you're expecting it to. Processing.js reads the `data-processing-sources` attribute on load. It doesn't keep watching it for changes. You might want to look into using instance mode and instantiating the sketch yourself when you make the change.

Comment: okay, i don't get it sorry, can i ask for a little example?

Comment: Sure, there are examples in [the Processing.js reference](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html). Do a search for the word "instance".

Comment: i'll do it. thank you!